# Error: Expected a Resource or Concept in hyperledger composer

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-chaincode

When I try to execute the transaction in composer-playground I got an error: Expected a Resource or Concept and the error message says "Expected a Resource or Concept". 
the transaction name is "HireEmployee".

/*Here is my .cto file: */

```
namespace org.example.basic


/** 
*Asset Job Defenition
*/

enum JobState {
o OPEN
o ON_LIVE
o HIRED
}

concept JobDescription {
o String jobTitle
o String jobdescription
o String skill
o String Duration
}

asset Job identified by jobId {
o String jobId
--> Employer employer
--> Member hiredemployee optional
o Double budget
o JobState state
o JobDescription description
o Bid[] offers optional
}

/**
*Asset Forum Defenition
*/


asset Forum identified by forumId {
  o String forumId
  -->Member owner
  o String question
  o Solution[] solutions optional
}

/**
* Participants of the network
*/


abstract participant User identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

participant Member extends User {
 o Double expPoint
 o Double credit
}

participant Employer extends User {
  o Double credit
}

/**
*Transactions
*/

transaction Bid {
  o Double bidPrice
  -->Job job
  -->Member member
}


transaction HireEmployee {
  -->Job job
}

transaction Solution {
  o String answer
  -->Forum forum
  -->Member member

}
```

/**
chaincode file
 * Hire an Employee
 * @param {org.example.basic.HireEmployee} hire - the hire
 * @transaction
 */

```
async function hireEmployee(hire) {
    const job = hire.job;
    if (job.state !== 'OPEN') {
        throw new Error('This Job is Closed and Someone is Already Hired');
    }

    job.state = 'ON_LIVE';  
    let lowestOffer = null;
    let employee = null;
    let employer =null;

    if (job.offers && job.offers.length > 0) {
        // sort the bids by bidPrice
        job.offers.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (a.bidPrice - b.bidPrice);
        });
        lowestOffer = job.offers[0];
        if (lowestOffer.bidPrice >= 5 ) {
            // mark the job as Hired
            job.state = 'HIRED';
            let employer = job.employer;
            let employee = lowestOffer.member;

            console.log('#### employer balance before: ' + employer.credit);
            employer.credit -= lowestOffer.bidPrice;
            console.log('#### employer balance after: ' + employer.credit);
            // update the balance of the buyer
            console.log('#### Employee balance before: ' + employee.credit);
            employee.credit += lowestOffer.bidPrice;
            console.log('#### buyer balance after: ' + employee.credit);
            // mark the hire employee
            job.hiredemployee = employee;

            job.offers = null;
        }
    }

     // save the bid
    const jobRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.basic.Job');
    await jobRegistry.update(job);

    if (job.state === 'HIRED') {
        // save the buyer
        const memberRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.basic.Member');
        await memberRegistry.update(employee);

        const userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.basic.Employer');
        await userRegistry.update(employer);
    }


}
```

Comment: Share your `Bid` transaction code also.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line within the function call I changed "const" to "let". I was able to make a test transaction in the Hyperledger Composer playground with this modification. Could you check if that works for you?

```
/** 
* Hire an Employee 
* @param {org.example.basic.HireEmployee} hire - the hire 
* @transaction 
*/

async function hireEmployee(hire) {
    let job = hire.job;
    if (job.state !== 'OPEN') {
        throw new Error('This Job is Closed and Someone is Already Hired');
    }

    job.state = 'ON_LIVE';  
    let lowestOffer = null;
    let employee = null;
    let employer =null;

    if (job.offers && job.offers.length > 0) {
        // sort the bids by bidPrice
        job.offers.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (a.bidPrice - b.bidPrice);
        });
        lowestOffer = job.offers[0];
        if (lowestOffer.bidPrice >= 5 ) {
            // mark the job as Hired
            job.state = 'HIRED';
            let employer = job.employer;
            let employee = lowestOffer.member;

            console.log('#### employer balance before: ' + employer.credit);
            employer.credit -= lowestOffer.bidPrice;
            console.log('#### employer balance after: ' + employer.credit);
            // update the balance of the buyer
            console.log('#### Employee balance before: ' + employee.credit);
            employee.credit += lowestOffer.bidPrice;
            console.log('#### buyer balance after: ' + employee.credit);
            // mark the hire employee
            job.hiredemployee = employee;

            job.offers = null;
        }
    }

     // save the bid
    const jobRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.basic.Job');
    await jobRegistry.update(job);

    if (job.state === 'HIRED') {
        // save the buyer
        const memberRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.basic.Member');
        await memberRegistry.update(employee);

        const userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.basic.Employer');
        await userRegistry.update(employer);
    }


}
```